# Scheme Error: #t is not a function [subset?, (anon)]

Tags: recursion, scheme

I am receiving two errors and im clearly not understanding something here. The first comes when the inputs are both sets. This is the error it gives me:

```
Error: #t is not a function [subset?, (anon)]
```

The second comes when A or S is not a set and it his the else statement. I get this:

```
Error: execute: unbound symbol: "else" [subset?, is-set?]
```

My code is as follows:

```
(define (is-set? L)
    (if (list? L)
        (cond
            ((null? L) #t)
            ((member (car L)(cdr L)) #f)
            (else (is-set? (cdr L)))
        )
    (else #f)
    )
)



(define (subset? A S)
    (if ((is-set? A) and (is-set? S))
        (cond
            ((null? A) #t)
            ((member (car A) S)
                 (subset? (cdr A) S))
          (else #f))
    (else #f))
)

(subset? '(1 3 5) '(1 2 3 5 6))

;;(subset? '(1 3 5) 1)
```

The is-set? function works and has the exact same syntax "((null? L) #t)" as "((null? A) #t)"
Does it have something to do with the fact that subset? takes two parameters?

I am testing this on https://repl.it/languages/scheme im not sure if that would make a difference either.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ((is-set? A) and (is-set? S))
> ```

Scheme doesn't have infix operators. `(exp exp*)` is the syntax for a function call where the first expression evaluates to a function, which is then called with the values of the other expressions as arguments.

So the above is interpreted as a function call where `(is-set? A)` is the function and `and` and `(is-set? S)` are the arguments. The first problem with that is that `(is-set? A)` isn't actually a function (it's a Boolean), which is what the error message is telling you.

> ```
> (else #f)
> ```

`if` does not use an `else` keyword. The else case of an `if` is simply given as the second expression to `if`. That is, instead of `(if condition exp1 (else exp2))`, you should write `(if condition exp1 exp2)`.

The reason that you don't run into the same error with your first function is that you never call `is-set?` with a non-list, so it never reaches the else-case and never finds the error.

Comment: thank you! this helped a lot. And you are right, that did not work in the first one.